# Why does my Javascript code unexpectedly say my String value is Not a number (NaN)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting a javascript error Not a number "NaN" in the textarea field.

I want to select a string from the autocomplete jqueryui and display the selected field into the textarea. Numeric values in the Json array display properly, but string values display NaN.

This is My json array:

```
 var financialClasses=[
                "abc",
                "PQR",
                "xyz" ];


// these are the functions for selecting multiple values in the autocomplete textbox

function split( val ) { return val.split( /,\s*/ );    }

function extractLast( term ) { return split( term ).pop();    }  


// This function logs the selected field in the textarea


 function financialclasses_log(message)  
{
            $( "#financialclasses-log" )
.append( message+", ").prependTo( "#financialclasses-log" ); }


    $( "#financialclasses" )/* this function is required when selecting multiple values */
                .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) { event.preventDefault(); } })

              .autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                            financialClasses, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                    },
                    focus: function() {
                        // prevent value inserted on focus
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {

                        financialclasses_log( ui.item ?
                            + ui.item.value:
                            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );

                        var terms = split( this.value );
                        // remove the current input
                        terms.pop();
                        // add the selected item
                        terms.push( ui.item.value);
                        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                        terms.push( "" );
                        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                        $(this).val("");
                        return false;
                    }
                });

// here is the html




<div id="financialclass" class="autocomplete_divs" class="ui-widget">
                <fieldset style="padding:0px">
                    <a href="addlist.jsp" style="float:right; margin-right:5px">Add List</a><br>
                    <label for="financialclasses"></label>
                    <input id="financialclasses" size="25">
                    <br>
                    <textarea id="financialclasses-log" class="log" class="ui-widget-content"></textarea>
                    <legend title="Financial Classes"><b>Financial Classes</b></legend>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/gEkWF/2/

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
+ ui.item.value
```

is using a unary `+` operator that coerces the value into a number. An attempt to coerce a non-numeric string to a number will yield `NaN`.

Remove the `+` from that line and your code should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gEkWF/6/

Comment: No worries! As Dijkstra said: "If debugging is the process of removing bugs, then programming must be the process of putting them in."

Comment: One more question regarding the textarea field, once I deleted an entry from the textarea and then while again trying to select from the autocomplete field any new string does not show in the textarea.